# Building an older Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to do this for a while now. I wasn't able to get a build on my local machine so I went the Docker route. I was able to successfully the use docker image devel-gpu to build Tensorflow. The problem is that it built the latest and greatest (2.5). I have searched and searched for a way to build an older 2.x version but have had no luck.

How do you build, say TensorFlow 2.1 using docker?

I seemed like they quit making docker images for individual versions that contained the source code to build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using already built images there are older versions available on Docker Hub. Here is a link for 2.1: https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=1&name=2.1 This is the easiest way to obtain an older version.

If you want to build it yourself:

1. Clone the repository:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git && cd tensorflow
```

2. Switch to the desired release:

```sh
git checkout v2.1.0
```

3. You'll find Dockerfiles in `tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/` but before building I recommend you to check out `tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/README.md` for exact building instructions. For version 2.1.0 it states that you have to run build command setting context to the directory with the `README.md`. That is:

```sh
cd tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles
docker build -f ./dockerfiles/cpu.Dockerfile -t tf .
```

And that's pretty much it, when building is finished you'll have an image named `tf:latest` (customize with flag `-t` in build command).